# Entity Framework keyword search map to multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to make a keyword search in my product database. My current database is structured like this:

```
- Catetory
-- SubCategory
--- Products
```

The idea is to make a Keyword and KeyworkRef table, so one keyword can be mapped to multiple entries (and types) to make better wildcard match performance. The keyword table contains the keyword, and the KeyworkRef contains the mappings to the result entries, like this:

**Keyword table**

```
-----------------------
| Id | Keyword        |
----------------------
| 1  | keyword_one    |
-----------------------
```

**KeywordRef table**

The Type column being an enum or something like that. RefId being the primary key in the related Type table.

```
----------------------------------------
| Id | KeywordId | Type        | RefId |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | Product     | 398   |
| 2  | 1         | Category    | 10    |
| 3  | 1         | SubCategory | 3     |
----------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to query this structure with Entity Framework? Or is there another structure that fits the purpose better?

Comment: This is called *polymorphic associations*. Have fun :)

Comment: so is it better to incur the cost the time of maintenance (add, update,delete) or at the time of query? what happens when a keyword is changed?  How will concurrent access to XRef work? If queries hugely out number maintenance, go ahead create a cross reference. you are in for a fun time maintaining it.  Consider parallel thread Queries on the 3 tables to improve "user" response time. And let DB do its job.